# Apache camel routing with Spring security goes to Grace Period

Tags: apache-camel

I am using apache camel blueprint DSL mode for my routing configurations. I am trying to add spring security for my routing. When I try to deploy my routing it goes to a Grace Period mentioning "waiting for name space handlers [http://camel.apache.org/schema/camel-spring-security]". Someone know the reason for this. Am I doing something wrong.

> 2016-08-30 14:20:53,326 | INFO  | -7.0.0.M2/deploy | BlueprintContainerImpl           | 28 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.6.1 | Bundle com.aaa.bbbbb.esb/0.0.1.SNAPSHOT is waiting for namespace handlers [http://camel.apache.org/schema/camel-spring-security]

My camel context xml heading in bluprint DSL is as follows.

```
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util "
xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf"
xmlns:spring-security="http://camel.apache.org/schema/camel-spring-security"
xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 
 http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd
https://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
http://camel.apache.org/schema/camel-spring-security http://camel.apache.org/schema/camel-spring-security/camel-spring-security.xsd">
```